# Solving Project Euler problem #48 in Scala

Tags: scala, project-euler

I'm trying to learn some Scala and decided to try to tackle some Project Euler problems.

For [problem #48](http://projecteuler.net/problem=48), coming from a Python background, my solution is the following one-liner:

```
print ( (1 to 1000).map(i => BigInt(i).pow(i)).sum % BigInt(10).pow(10) )
```

Is this idiomatic? Is there a simpler/more readable solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution is clean but doesn't **scale** well. A well known optimization for `a^k mod m` is to perform all computations modulus `m`. If `m` is sufficiently small, we furthermore can switch to native types (this is not the case here !).

```
val n = 1000
val m = BigInt(10).pow(10)
(for (i <- 1 to n) yield BigInt(i).modPow(i,m)).sum % m
```

Rounded avarage timing results (Scala 2.9.1 with `-optimize`) :

```
n                     1000     | 10000
Initial solution       4.8 ms  |  6700 ms
Fold left              4.8 ms  |  6700 ms
My humble version      0.5 ms  |     5 ms
```

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is totally valid. Instead of `xs.map(f).sum` it is possible to use `xs.foldLeft(init)(f)`:

```
(1 to 1000).foldLeft(BigInt(0)) {
  (sum, n) => sum+BigInt(n).pow(n)
}
// or with /: synonym for foldLeft
(BigInt(0) /: (1 to 1000)) {
  (sum, n) => sum+BigInt(n).pow(n)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer! Would using foldLeft be more efficient or is it just a matter of taste?
Also, I didn't know at all the /: syntax for foldLeft. Seems a bit cryptic TBH...

Comment: `foldLeft` should be more efficient because it does both operations (map+sum) in a single step. Thus, there is no unnecessary creation of an intermediate collection (from map), which can be allayed with lazy collections (like `.iterator` of `.view`). But, `foldLeft` should be more efficient, even with lazy collections.